# How to install Windows 7 onto MacOS Sierra without downgrading using BootCamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macos, dual-boot

How do I do a partitioned install of Windows7 on my MacOS sierra?

Sierra won't let me use boot camp assistant. I have a macbook air (late 2015) 8gb ram model. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 is not supported by Apple with your hardware.
The latest MacBook Air compatible with Windows 7 64 Bits is the [Early 2014 Macbook Air](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016#tables).

You can install [Windows 8.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457) or [Windows 10](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990).

Check your system compatibility on this [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048).